# how to use SQL group to filter rows with maximum date value

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Test
    (`Id` int, `value` varchar(20), `adate` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO Test
    (`Id`, `value`, `adate`)
VALUES
    (1, 100, '2014-01-01'),
    (1, 200, '2014-01-02'),
    (1, 300, '2014-01-03'),
    (2, 200, '2014-01-01'),
    (2, 400, '2014-01-02'),
    (2, 30 , '2014-01-04'),
    (3, 800, '2014-01-01'),
    (3, 300, '2014-01-02'),
    (3, 60 , '2014-01-04')
;
```

I want to achieve the result which selects only Id having max value of date. ie

Id ,value ,adate

```
 1, 300,'2014-01-03'     
 2, 30 ,'2014-01-04'     
 3, 60 ,'2014-01-04'
```

how can I achieve this using `group by`? I have done as follows but it is not working.

```
Select Id,value,adate
from Test
group by Id,value,adate
having adate = MAX(adate)
```

Can someone help with the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a DBMS that has analytical functions you can use ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT  Id, Value, ADate
FROM    (   SELECT  ID,
                    Value,
                    ADate,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Adate DESC) AS RowNum
            FROM    Test
        ) AS T
WHERE   RowNum = 1;
```

Otherwise you will need to use a join to the aggregated max date by Id to filter the results from `Test` to only those where the date matches the maximum date for that Id

```
SELECT  Test.Id, Test.Value, Test.ADate
FROM    Test
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  ID, MAX(ADate) AS ADate
            FROM    Test
            GROUP BY ID
        ) AS MaxT
            ON MaxT.ID = Test.ID
            AND MaxT.ADate = Test.ADate;
```

Answer (score 18):

Select the maximum dates for each id.

```
select id, max(adate) max_date
from test
group by id
```

Join on that to get the rest of the columns.

```
select t1.*
from test t1
inner join (select id, max(adate) max_date
            from test
            group by id) t2
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.adate = t2.max_date;
```

Comment: What if `adate` must be determined through 2 other columns that must be handled as union?

Comment: @FabianPicone: The principle is the same. Write a query that returns one row per "id", and join on it. You might have to write the UNION query, and then SELECT from it. (SELECT * FROM (SELECT...UNION SELECT...))

Answer (score 12):

Please try:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  tbl a
where 
  a.adate=(select MAX(adate) from tbl b where b.Id=a.Id)
```

Comment: I wonder why this is not considered the best solution.

Comment: Totally agree, this has been by far the easiest solution to understand and implement.

Answer (score -1):

I would try something like this

```
Select  t1.Id, t1.value, t1.adate
from    Test as t1
where   t1.adate = (select max(t2.adate) 
                    from Test as t2
                    where t2.id = t1.id)
```